# Embedding a bot on a website

Tags: javascript, botframework

Please I have been able to position the bot in its wanted position I need help with the toggling 
here is my code

```
(function () {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
    div.outerHTML = "<div id='botDiv' style='width: 400px; height: 438px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; right:0; z-index: 1000;><div  id='botTitleBar' style='height: 40px; width: 400px; position:fixed; background: #6819bf; cursor: pointer;'></div></div>";  
    BotChat.App({
      directLine: { secret: 'Your Secret Key Here' },
      user: { id: 'userid' },
      bot: { id: '' }
    }, document.getElementById("botDiv"));
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.target.matches = e.target.matches || e.target.msMatchesSelector;
      if (e.target.matches('#botTitleBar')) {
        var botDiv = document.querySelector('#botDiv');
        botDiv.style.height = botDiv.style.height == '400px' ? '38px' : '400px';
      };
    });
  }());
```

Comment: Hi @MuritalaJamiu, if the reply help you solve the problem, you can mark it as accepted answer, which would help other community members quickly find it to solve similar problem.

Answer (score 5):

> I have been able to position the bot in its wanted position I need help with the toggling

It seems that you position your chat bot at bottom right corner of web page, and now you want to toggle visibility of chat bot window. Based on your requirement and code snippet, I modify your code to achieve the requirement, the following code should work for you.

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
        div.outerHTML = "<div id='botDiv' style='width: 400px; height: 400px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; right:0; z-index: 1000;><div  id='botTitleBar' style='height: 40px; width: 400px; position:fixed; background: #6819bf; cursor: pointer;'></div></div>";

        BotChat.App({
            directLine: { secret: 'Your Secret Key Here' },
            user: { id: 'userid' },
            bot: { id: '' }
        }, document.getElementById("botDiv"));

        //specify id for webchat header

        document.getElementsByClassName("wc-header")[0].setAttribute("id", "chatbotheader");

        document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (e) {

            e.target.matches = e.target.matches || e.target.msMatchesSelector;
            //detect if user clicked webchat header
            if (e.target.matches('#chatbotheader')) {
                var botDiv = document.querySelector('#botDiv');
                botDiv.style.height = botDiv.style.height == '400px' ? '38px' : '400px';
            };
        });
    }());
</script>
```

**Test result:**

*1)open webchat window:*

[image]

*2)close webchat window:*

[image]