# How to solve BotChat.App Uncaught ReferenceError?

Tags: c#, html, botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I m trying to use some code which i find in [Embedding a bot on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932737/embedding-a-bot-on-a-website) .
I know it have been some updates, my question is if BotChat.App is avaible to use.
Because i use the BotChat.App and gave me this error Uncaught ReferenceError: BotChat is not defined.

I try to change it to  window.WebChat.renderWebChat and it works but gave me the error in this line document.getElementsByClassName("wc-header")[0].setAttribute("id", "chatbotheader");

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
   <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
        #mychat {
            margin: 10px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 30px;
            right: 10px;
            z-index: 1000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <!--other page contents-->
        <img id="mychat" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD7i4.png" style="float:right" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    (function () {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
        div.outerHTML = "<div id='botDiv' style='width: 400px; height: 0px; margin:10px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; right:0; z-index: 1000;><div  id='botTitleBar' style='height: 40px; width: 400px; position:fixed; cursor: pointer;'></div></div>";
        BotChat.App({
            directLine: { secret: 'myAppSecret' },
        }, document.getElementById("botDiv"));

        document.getElementsByClassName("wc-header")[0].setAttribute("id", "chatbotheader");
        document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.target.matches = e.target.matches || e.target.msMatchesSelector;
            if (e.target.matches('#chatbotheader')) {
                var botDiv = document.querySelector('#botDiv');

                botDiv.style.height = "0px";

                document.getElementById("mychat").style.display = "block";
            };
        });

        document.getElementById("mychat").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

            document.getElementById("botDiv").style.height = '500px';

            e.target.style.display = "none";
        })
    }());
</script>
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: BotChat is not defined html:31

Comment: Put the code inside a Try/Catch to see the error, if after that you still don't know what to do, edit the question with the error that is given by the Catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests this is due to the fact that , though you utilize BotChat.App, you haven't got a reference to `BotChat`.

Try importing `<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>` within the header section.